# Sort table with million rows , LinQ connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I've got a problem and no idea how to solve it in SQL server 2012 ,

I have table with +5,000,000 row record ( ID , Link ), 
but when I query`select N row` shows error `"Request timed out."`

**Code:**

```
public void _Read()
{

    LinQDataContext _DB = new LinQDataContext();

    var _img = _DB.HotelImages.Where(o => o.ID_Hotel == Hotel_DA.ID_Hotel);

    string _imghtml = "";
    foreach (var item in _img)
    {
        _imghtml = _imghtml + "<a href=''><img src='" + item.Url_Image + "' alt=''></a>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is in code you call to select N rows?

Comment: Is your table indexed?  How many records are you expecting to be returned by this query?  Also, is the web request timing out, or is it the Sql Server request?

Comment: when i select return random record , web and sql server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A covering index combined with fetching only the required columns (as already suggested) will result in the best performance improvement:

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ID_Hotel ON YourTable(ID_Hotel)
INCLUDE (Url_Image)
```

You should also make sure you context is disposed. And i suggest you to use a string builder instead of concatenanting strings.

```
string html;
var builder = new StringBuilder();
using (LinQDataContext _DB = new LinQDataContext())
{

    var urls = _DB.HotelImages.Where(o => o.ID_Hotel == Hotel_DA.ID_Hotel)
               .Select(x => x.Url_Image);

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        builder.Append("<a href=''><img src='")
               .Append(url)
               .Append("'")
               .Append("alt=''></a>");
    }
}
html = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are fetching complete `HotelImage` objects. Maybe they also contain blobs? You should narrow down the data you fetch from the database by selecting *only* `Url_Image`, because that's the only property you use:

```
var _img = _DB.HotelImages.Where(o => o.ID_Hotel == Hotel_DA.ID_Hotel)
              .Select(x => x.Url_Image);
```

And then

```
_imghtml = _imghtml + "<a href=''><img src='" + item + "' alt=''></a>";
```